# Corpser or Vile Roaches in HOTS?

Tags: starcraft-2

[image: Roach Choice]
Evolution Chamber choices in the HOTS campaign: one is between Corpser and Vile Roaches.
Trying to avoid buyer's remorse with my choice here :)

Corpser roaches create 2 roachlings when they kill which have a limited life like locusts from the swarm host, while Vile roaches have an attack that slows enemy units by 75%.

What are the advantages of each? Which work better in a mixed army? What is the best mutation depending on what type of Roach I chose?

---

**Mutations**

- **Adaptive Plating**: Gain +3 armor when life falls below 50%
- **Hydriodic Bile**: Gain +8 damage vs. light units.
- **Tunneling Claws**: Move at full speed when burrowed, and gain 100% life regeneration rate.

Comment: There are not "3 Evolution chamber choices in HotS campaign", there are "3 Evolution Chamber choice *examples on Battle.net site*".

Comment: Fair enough - those are the ones I'd seen in the campaign so far.

Comment: All the evolvable units are listed on Abathur's Cookbook achievement: Zergling, Baneling, Roach, Hydralisk, Mutalisk, Swarm Host, Ultralisk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's first look a their abilities

**Corpser Strain**

- More overall life for you army from extra spawns.
- More damage from extra spawns.
- Require kills to spawn units with limited life.

**Vile Strain**

- Reduces damage output from non-ability attacks.
- Prevents enemy escape and helps with own escape.
- Does not help you vs ability like High Templar's Psionic Storm.

Both give a nice boost in survivability, but also help with situations where they are not much use.

The choice comes down to if your playing style is lacking when it comes to taking down large groups of enemies or slowing down the damage from a few big enemies.

Since I personally thought it would be harder dealing with the big enemies I went for the Vile Strain to reduce the incoming damage from them.

Comment: @OrcJMR it reduce enemy damage by slowing there attack http://i.stack.imgur.com/uXddc.jpg

Comment: Where attack speed? It does reduce enemy "damage per second" or "damage output". Unit's "damage" attribute remains unchanged. In Starcraft II there is some difference between rapid weak attacks and slow powerful attacks.

Comment: Yes - I chose Vile as well, thinking it works better in a composition with other units.

Answer (score -2):

nonononono.  You send in a bunch of spawns as tanks, the AI auto acquires them (since you are only playing vs AI in campaign at this point), and your army is then invincible from there on out as you kill more and more and get more spawns/tanks in an endless cycle till the enemy is dead.